# On iPhone, do text only banner ads make as much money?

Tags: iphone, admob, iad

My app is in landscape and I am using kGADAdSizeSmartBannerLandscape to create banners across the screen. I am using AdMob Mediation with AdMob and iAd only.

The thing is, these size ads (480x32)or(960x64) are text only for the iphone. Does anyone have any experience of these size and type of ads. Can I expect a reduced fill rate?

The alternative is to use the standard portrait banner size which means the ad will not stretch across the whole screen and will be much fatter.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use the ad size that best fits your application.

AdMob Text ads can be manipulated to fit the full width size.  Images can't change their resolution, but since 480x32 is a popular format for iPhone, there may also be AdMob image inventory for this size at some point.